# Unable to parse the string to date format

Tags: java

In my application i got a date string has  '2017-08-08T07:32:24Z' i need to parse this string to date. I have written a code for that

```
        String string = "2017-08-08T07:32:24Z";
        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(" yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
        Date date = format.parse(string);
```

on executing the code i got the below error :

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2017-08-08T07:32:24Z"
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.rapidvalue.accurate.utils.AutomationMail.getMailBodyData(AutomationMail.java:367)
at com.rapidvalue.accurate.utils.AutomationMail.sendMail(AutomationMail.java:205)
at com.rapidvalue.accurate.reporting.AutomationListener.onExecutionFinish(AutomationListener.java:1768)
at org.testng.TestNG.runExecutionListeners(TestNG.java:1158)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1123)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)
```

can any one help on this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

Comment: remove the blank at the beginnig of the pattern: `" yyyy`

Comment: @Jens says right remove white space. It will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove the splace before yyyy. It should work.

```
String string = "2017-08-08T07:32:24Z";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
format.parse(string);
```